# Firefox not loading jQuery plugin when entering URL

Tags: jquery, firefox, plugins, loading, onload

I'm having a very annoying issue on Firefox 3.6.8.
I have this sample plugin:

```
    (function($){  

    $.fn.test_plugin = function(settings){  

        $(this).load(function(settings){
            alert('ok');
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

And at the bottom of the html page something like this:

```
        $(function(){
        $("#image1").test_plugin();
    });
```

So Basically this should show na alert message fter the pages loads, and it does, except, when you type the url manually on Firefox. If I refresh the page no problem, but on redirect or manually typing the URL it's not. I got no errors and from the firebug everything seems to be fine. This only happens on FF, I got no probs on Safari, chrome, IE.

Any idea why this is ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, thanks for your replies, however I've seem to fixed it.

I've just used

```
$(window).load(function(settings){
```

instead of

```
$(this).load(function(settings){
```

It fixed the problem and it's working fine on the other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

See the [jQuery API entry for load](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

> .load( url, [ data ], [ complete(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) ] )

The first argument to load is a URL.  This can optionally be followed by data and a callback function.  You did not include a URL in your call to load.

It looks like you're trying to write your first jQuery plugin.  If that's the case, I'd recommend reading [A Plugin Development Pattern](http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/10/a-plugin-development-pattern).

I built [a Gist](http://gist.github.com/468626) based on this that you can also look at.

Comment: Great resource  on that link. Thanks

Comment: Reigel is correct, I didn't see the separate entry for load-event.

Comment: Also note, if you're trying to run an event after the window has loaded, the best option is going to be $(document).ready().  http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems that you might have tried to use the jquery load function as a page unload event which is wrong. The load function is for Ajax call which as stated by calvinf requires a URL parameter among other parameters to make the call to.

But read some more and your are well on your way to write jquery plugins :)